# How to compare if two cells have same characters in any order in excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to compare if two cells in Excel contain the same characters, which could be in any order, using Excel based formulae.

For example, if:

```
A1= Japan;US 

A2= US;Japan
```

--EDIT--

Another example,

```
    C1= abcefg

    C2= efgabc
```

In both these cases, when I check whether A1=A2 or C1=C2, it should give me TRUE since all the characters in both the cells are exactly the same, albeit in different order.

Ps - These cells could have any character length.

Comment: is this always the case ? you have different countries with a `;` in between ?

Comment: Hi Shai, 

No, this is not always the case. This was just an example, the cells could have any value with no fixed pattern.

Comment: How do you know that you want `Japan;US` or the other way around if you have other characters in the cell?

Comment: Hi Kylo, 

I don't know that. Essentially, I just want to compare if two rows are duplicate or not, but not in a strict sense. By that I mean, a cell that contains "abcdef" is = to another cell that contains "acdefb" since they have the same characters, say A1 and A2, respectively.

If I simply look-up if A1=A2, then it will give me FALSE, since excel cares about the sequence in which the characters appear. For my project, i don't.

Comment: Can they have two or more more of the same characters?

Comment: Yes, they can have anything. I want excel to compare them character for character and return TRUE if same characters are found in both the cells.

Comment: If the answer solves your question, please mark one as solved. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a single function that will answer your problem.

I made a little script that will compare two cells, to test it, put your values in `Range("A1")` and `Range("A2")`. Being that you are only comparing two values, looping like this will have a very minimal performance hit.

```
Sub d()
   Dim ValueOne As String
   Dim ValueTwo As String
   Dim charVal
   Dim sString
   Dim char
   Dim boolVal As Boolean


      ValueOne = Cells(1, 1).Value
      ValueTwo = Cells(2, 1).Value

      boolVal = True

      If Len(ValueTwo) = Len(ValueOne) Then
        charVal = StrConv(ValueOne, vbUnicode)
        charVal = Left(charVal, Len(charVal) - 1)
        sString = Split(charVal, Chr(0))
            For Each char In sString
                If Len(ValueTwo) = Len(Replace(ValueTwo, char, "")) Or Len(Replace(ValueTwo, char, "")) <> Len(Replace(ValueOne, char, "")) Then
                   boolVal = False
                   GoTo nxt
                End If
            Next
        charVal = StrConv(ValueTwo, vbUnicode)
        charVal = Left(charVal, Len(charVal) - 1)
        sString = Split(charVal, Chr(0))
            For Each char In sString
                If Len(ValueOne) = Len(Replace(ValueOne, char, "")) Or Len(Replace(ValueTwo, char, "")) <> Len(Replace(ValueOne, char, "")) Then
                   boolVal = False
                   GoTo nxt
                End If
            Next
       Else
            boolVal = False
       End If
nxt:
      If boolVal = False Then
         MsgBox "Strings are different"
      Else
         MsgBox "Strings are the same"
      End If

End Sub
```

Also, if you wanted this as a function, you could very easily change to one just by doing this,

```
Function Compare(ValueOne As String, ValueTwo As String)

   Dim charVal
   Dim sString
   Dim char
   Dim boolVal As Boolean      

         ' Insert same code as above here   


          'End Insert same code as above here
      If boolVal = False Then
          Compare = True
      Else
          Compare = True
      End If
End Function
```

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you, but your answer is wrong. Try it with these two values `iivan` and `ivaan`.

Comment: Ok. Probably it is a good idea to change the code in the `Ifs` like this: `If Len(ValueTwo) <> Len(Replace(ValueTwo, char, "")) Then`

Comment: @Vityata My bad, left out an `or` statement (pretty hard when your on a phone doing this, LOL), edited to fix.

Comment: @KyloRen - depends who are you speaking with :D

Comment: Still, why do you need an `OR` there? I think that only `If Len(ValueTwo) <> Len(Replace(ValueTwo, char, "")) Then` would be enough, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Vityata, b/c you still need to make sure that both strings have the same amount identical chars in them, without that `or` you would get some funcky results as you saw. Changing the If statements from `=` to `<>` will get you the same net value only opposite, so no real value I would not think.

Comment: Can you come up with an example where only this: `If Len(ValueTwo) <> Len(Replace(ValueTwo, char, "")) Then` would not work?

Comment: Thanks a lot guys!! I really appreciate your help :-)

Answer (score 1):

The idea is the following: we take the two strings (in `Sub Test`) and we compare them in the `CompareMe` function. The idea of the comparison is to cast them to arrays (`StrToArray`), then sort the array (BubbleSort). At the end, the result of `(Join(varStr1, "") = Join(varStr2, ""))` is the answer of the question.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()

    Debug.Print CompareMe("Japan;US", "US;Japan")
    Debug.Print CompareMe("abcefg", "efgabc")
    Debug.Print CompareMe("abcefg", "e1fgabc")
    Debug.Print CompareMe("vit", "vitt")

End Sub

Public Function CompareMe(str1 As String, str2 As String) As Boolean

    Dim varStr1             As Variant
    Dim varStr2             As Variant

    ReDim varStr1(Len(str1))
    ReDim varStr2(Len(str2))

    varStr1 = StrToArray(str1)
    varStr2 = StrToArray(str2)

    Call BubbleSort(varStr1)
    Call BubbleSort(varStr2)

    CompareMe = (Join(varStr1, "") = Join(varStr2, ""))

End Function

Public Sub BubbleSort(ByRef list As Variant)

    Dim First           As Long
    Dim Last            As Long
    Dim i               As Long
    Dim j               As Long
    Dim Temp            As String

    First = LBound(list)
    Last = UBound(list)

    For i = First To Last - 1
        For j = i + 1 To Last
            If list(i) > list(j) Then
                Temp = list(j)
                list(j) = list(i)
                list(i) = Temp
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub

Public Function StrToArray(str As String) As Variant

    Dim buff()      As String
    Dim i           As Long

    ReDim buff(Len(str) - 1)

    For i = 1 To Len(str)
        buff(i - 1) = Mid$(str, i, 1)
    Next

    StrToArray = buff

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Vityata!